# Azure az cli Docker Hub Web App ressource configuration

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cli, dockerhub

I'm trying to setup a script for automate the creation of a new environment for my app, and i need a docker webapp.
The problem is that i need to pull the image from docker hub.
When i create an env from the interface in juste setup it like that :
[image: Screen of a docker configuration]

The problem is that i don't find out how i can configure the "Source de registre" on Docker Hub by the az cli.

For now the command i'm using to create a new web app ressource is this one

`az webapp create -g name_of_group -p name_of_plan -n resource-test2 -i https://registry.hub.docker.com/publisher/name_of_image:version -s name_of_image -w my_password`

The problem of this command is that it give me this configuration

[image: Screenshot of a configuration]

Which doesn't work because i can't get logged in (probably because it's not configured as a Docker Hub registre).

Do you know how i can specify this configuration in my az cli command ? Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: No ... still no news, still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

To deploy the images stored in a private registry or the Docker Hub, you can set the environment variables below:

- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME - The username for the ACR server.
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL - The full URL to the ACR server. (For example, https://my-server.azurecr.io.)
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD - The password for the ACR server.

Get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-environment-variables). And you can use the CLI command [`az webapp config appsettings set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_appsettings_set) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently had the same problem deploying azure cloud webapp from a container in my private docker hub repo. UI experience works fine but when I do it using azure cli with 'az webapp create ...' ended up with same problem. I was able to fix it by using 'az webapp config container set ...' command after creating the webapp. See below and in my [github repo](https://github.com/oyundev/tweb1)

```sh
# First create the webapp with a docker container:
~$ az webapp create -n $webAppName -g $resGroup -p $servicePlan -i $containerImg -s $dockerUsr -w $dockerPass --tags Lifecycle=Test
# Update docker container settings with your private docker hub repo credentials:
~$ az webapp config container set --name $webAppName --resource-group $resGroup --docker-custom-image-name 'DOCKER|dockeruser/myrepo:tweb1' --docker-registry-server-url 'https://index.docker.io/v1' --docker-registry-server-user 'dockeruser' --docker-registry-server-password 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
```